# Why can't you intern bytes in Python?

Tags: python

As mentioned in Python documentation, [`sys.intern()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?highlight=intern#sys.intern) only accepts string objects. I understand why mutable types are not supported by `sys.intern`. But there's at least one more immutable type for which interning would make sense: `bytes`.

So here's my question: is there any particular reason why Python interning doesn't support `bytes`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was suggested [a decade ago on the Python-Dev mailing list](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2013-September/128814.html).  The answer is:

> The main difference is that sys.intern() will remove the interned
> strings when every external reference vanishes. It requires either weakref'ability (which both str and bytes lack) or special cooperation from the object destructor (which is why sys.intern() is restricted to str instead of working with arbitrary objects).

Clearly it is *possible* to add support for `bytes`, but it seems very niche, not something standard Python is likely to add.  That doesn't stop you from making your own equivalent, unless the whole reason you want it is for dictionary key lookup speed.  I've never seen anyone use `bytes` as dictionary keys, but I'm sure some people do.

Comment: Keep in mind, the primary purpose of `str` interning is to support the implicit `dict` lookups involved in stuff like method, attribute, globals and builtins lookup, all of which involve lookups in `str`-keyed `dict`s under the hood (`dict` itself has special cases to support/optimize this as well). The overhead paid for `str` (storing a flag indicating if it's interned, a precheck for that flag when performing comparisons) is worth it when you regularly realize the benefits; this doesn't apply to `bytes`, so the costs would be paid without realizing the benefits.